Get a list of things
The documentation and the nomenclature is extremely confusing so excuse me if I do not use the correct terminus technicus.
I can do GET /services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/foo/describe to get a description of foo. But how do I get a list of foo records? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve_get.htm this want an ID but I don't have one. I just want to see the records... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm this wants an updated start date but I don't have one. I just want to see the records...

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve.htm is one API that lets you retrieve records. You probably want to step back and learn a bit more about the platform before implementing. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_overview

"Accesses records based on a specified object and record ID". Nope, that's not it. Here's a random REST API example which simply retrieves records https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list

Wrong link, apologies. Correct API is Query:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm

The REST resource you're looking for here is the query resource. The resources in the SObject "family" (for lack of a better word) generally require an Id or work on/return a single item.
You need to write a query to get a list of SObject records, and depending on how many records your query returns, you may need to make multiple API calls.
So the URL you'd be using should be something like
https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v60.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id%2C+name+FROM+Foo__c
Just like a normal SOQL query, you need a comma between each field that you want to include in the results.
%2C is a comma
use periods as normal for referencing related data on "parent" records
the + acts like a space (so we don't need to us the url-encoded space character, though either will work)

In the general sense, if you don't have an ID and you want to get one, you perform a query. You can use the REST query, GraphQL, SOAP Query, to name a few. You can also run reports, look at List Views, perform searches, which you can also do via SOSL. The problem is, there truly are a dazzling number of ways to get at the data.
Even once you get this far, you'll find that everyone wants to sell you their way of getting your data. MuleSoft, Informatica, Crystal Reports, DataLoader.io, etc. The list is nearly endless. Going one step further, you can even get at records directly through the API in Salesforce. Just click on the ⚙️ icon, then Developer Console, then Query Editor. From there, just use direct SOQL, and you'll get the results immediately.
At any rate, I do hope one of the links above proves useful.
